# Postgres JSONB, query first appearance of inner field

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

Trying to query product_id and inner JSONB value "quantity_on_hand" with "unit:one". Below is example table

Products table

```
| product_id | data         |
| --------   | -------------|
| 00445      |  {"storage"...}| - rest of data specified right below
{
  "storage": [
    {
      "unit": "one",
      "quantity": 3,
    },
    {
      "unit": "two",
      "quantity": 2,
    }
}
```

I found a query:

```
SELECT product_id, e -> 'quantity' as quant 
FROM Products t, 
     jsonb_array_elements(t.value->'storage') e 
WHERE (product_id) IN (('00445'));
```

The query returns following output:

```
product_id | quant 
00445      | 3  
00445      | 2
```

Please advise how to set rule: "quantity_on_hand" with "unit:one" to return only:

product_id | quant
00445      | 3

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a clause for filtering the result of the `jsonb_array_elements` to only include elements where the JSON key `"unit"`'s value is `"one"`:

```sql
SELECT product_id,
       e -> 'quantity' AS quant
  FROM Products t,
       JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(t.value -> 'storage') e
 WHERE (product_id) IN (('00445'))
   AND e ->> 'unit' = 'one';
```

This should give:

```
 product_id | quant
------------+-------
 1          | 3
(1 row)
```

See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-json.html for more information on JSONB operators and functions in Postgres.